# Left align text below center aligned text

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if it is possible to left align text below center aligned text, so that both texts start from same position.

In the example figure. The TITLEs are center aligned and the copy below is left aligned.

How can you realise something like this with CSS?

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle to start from

https://jsfiddle.net/j5p7v8m9/

```
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center;">TITLE</p>
  <p style="text-align: left;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share JSFiddle or something?

Comment: You can center the title, and use a `width:0` for the text, letting it overflow, but it's messy, and not perfectly aligned

Comment: @SuthanBala I added a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j5p7v8m9/

Comment: what determines the width of the left aligned text?

Comment: Anyway, the only way I see this happening is with absolute positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/bj5m8v34/2/, perhaps can use js so that it extends the container box to the correct height

Comment: Thanks @Pete. Your solutions works very well!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. I've updated your JSFiddle. You need to add some wrappers for each divs, then you can centerize the title as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="contents">
      <p class="title">TITLE</p>
      <p class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      </p>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="contents">
      <p class="title">TITLE</p>
      <p class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="contents">
      <p class="title">TITLE</p>
      <p class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  display: block;
}
.col{
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.contents{
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.title{
  text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/53oLpvqg/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with bootstrap css it my help you for easy css.

```
<div class="col">
<p class="text-center">Title</p>
<p class="text-left">Test content Content</p>


</div>
```

Check Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0h2nmj3r/

Answer (score 0):

*Look at other answers for directions on align text this is answer will help with getting that column effect

The best way to get three columns like that is to use a type of special display in css called "flex". Flex allows you to easily align elements within the parent html element.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction : row;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.text-box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-start;
  width:20%;
}

p{
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="text-box">
  <p >TITLE</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </p>
</div>

<div class="text-box">
  <p >TITLE</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </p>
</div>

<div class="text-box">
  <p >TITLE</p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

So as you can see I have applied flex to both the container and the text-box's. Left align can be used like in these other answers but i opted for align-items:flex-start so any element within the text-box will be aligned to the left.

By setting justify-content:space-around it makes each element within the container have equal space around it so if you were to change the window size the spaces would be relative and change. I would recommend studying more about flex and grid to improve your css skills.